Custom redirect filter for users logged in with certain roles on sites they are not [Authorized] to access?
I have this .NET 9.0 project where I need to create, preferably, an attribute I can add to controller actions that would have users logged in with certain roles, for example "Test".
Now, every time a user with the role "Test" tries to access my admin pages (localhost/admin), they get redirected to the url access-denied?returnUrl=%2Fadmin. For users who are not logged in, or do not have the "Test" role, I want this behaviour.
However, if a user is logged in, and has the role "Test", then the user should instead be redirected to a different site. So, every time a logged in user, that has the role "Test", and they try to access a site where they are not Authorized, they should instead be redirected to www.example.com.
I would prefer to use attribute tags for controller actions, but if I can create a global handler or filter that just redirects "Test" users every time they try to access a site where they are not authorized (e.g. gets the access-denied URL), that would be great too.
